# SQL script to remind contract end date

Tags: sql-server

I need help to translate the following into an SQL script. Hopefully someone can share some info on this. I have done the following example in Excel and I'm hoping that I can do something similar in the SQL tables.

The purpose of this is when a contract is going to expire in 3 days time, an email will be send out.

Contract Start Date : 15 Aug
Contract days : 30
Contract End date : Contract start date + Contract days

days from expiration : 3

trigger : IF(days from expiration=3,"Send email","")

Thank you very much all.

Comment: Maybe not trigger but SQL Agent Job that every day will check this. Write simple query like `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE DATEDIFF(...) < 3` and send result to email

Comment: Thanks, but I need sql to help calculate the contract end date together with the trigger. In my sql tables I have created contract start date, contract end date (which will be auto calculated) and expiration. I will assume trigger will be a trigger in SQL